# Eclipse bug - Error in my Android project's without real error

Tags: android, eclipse, project

All of my Android projects have error sign now, but there is no error in the project. I didn't edit anything but there is an error sign by each project now. The sign appeared first by 3-4 projects only, I didn't edit absolutely any of my projects and the sign appears now by all my projects. What can this be and how could I resolve this - I don't want to rebuild my projects from the beginning, of course :)
I already tried project->clean but I have again the error sign.

Comment: are you using mac os maybe? have you upgraded to Lion recently?
anyway, check your properties, see what is listed under Java Compiler and Android.

Comment: So in the Problems view, there will be hopefully be markers with explanations of the issue(s). Have you looked at those? What do they say?

Comment: these often relates to problems in project settings rather than code, verify your build path, libs, compiler version etc in the project properties

Answer (score 4):

If you go to `Window -> Show View -> Problems` you can see exactly why the errors are there and take action accordingly. Usually, if there is no obvious error, cleaning your project can resolve the issue. However, there is clearly something else going on for you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1) Right click on the project (in Project Explorer)

2) You should see Android tools towards the end. Click on it to get a list of options

3) Choose "Fix project properties"

Shash

Comment: didn't knew about that "fix project properties", sounds cool, what does it do behind the scene exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried signing your application?  Go through these steps and see what happens
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

go to `Project>>Clean` ..try this..

Comment: I already tried project->clean but I have again the error sign.